# Failed to compile vertex shader GPUImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, gpuimage

I am trying to use some custom filters in GPUImage and I have some vertex and fragment shaders that I would like to use. When I try to use the filters I get an errors saying my shaders failed to compile and it throws an exception of `Filter shader link failed`

Here is my code to setup my camera

```
videoCamera = [[GPUImageVideoCamera alloc] initWithSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh cameraPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];
    videoCamera.outputImageOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
    videoCamera.horizontallyMirrorFrontFacingCamera = NO;
    videoCamera.horizontallyMirrorRearFacingCamera = NO;
    videoCamera.frameRate = 30;

    filter = [[GPUImageFilter alloc]initWithVertexShaderFromString:@"AlphaDisplayShader" fragmentShaderFromString:@"AlphaDisplayShader"];

    [videoCamera addTarget:filter];
    GPUImageView *filterView = [[GPUImageView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    [self.view addSubview:filterView];

    [filter addTarget:filterView];

    [videoCamera startCameraCapture];
```

And for my shaders I have:

`AlphaDisplayShader.fsh`

```
varying highp vec2 textureCoordinate;
precision mediump float;

uniform sampler2D videoFrame;
uniform float inputAlpha;

void main()
{
    //vec4 textureColor = texture2D(videoFrame, textureCoordinate);
    //gl_FragColor = 0.5 * textureColor;

    gl_FragColor = texture2D(videoFrame, textureCoordinate);


    //normal
    gl_FragColor.a *= inputAlpha;

    //gl_FragColor.r=1.0;

    //lightrail
    //gl_FragColor.r *= inputColor.a;
    //gl_FragColor.g *= inputColor.a;
    //gl_FragColor.b *= inputColor.a;

}
```

`AlphaDisplayShader.vsh`

```
attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec4 inputTextureCoordinate;

varying vec2 textureCoordinate;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = position;
    textureCoordinate = inputTextureCoordinate.xy;
}
```

I am attempting to simulate long exposure photographs with a video using these filters, does anyone see where my error lies? I am using the latest official release of Xcode as well.

Comment: you should use the same declaration for the varying in the FS and the VS. You use `highp` only in the FS.

Comment: @derhass I have updated both to use `highp` and I am still getting the same error.

Comment: @derhass I initially suspected that too. But after looking it up, `highp` is the default for vertex shaders. so that should be fine. In fact, after some more digging, I found this in the spec: "The precision of varying variables does not need to match."

Comment: @RetoKoradi: interesting. nice to know :)

Comment: Are your shader files correctly within your Copy Bundle Resources build phase? By default, Xcode treats shader files as source code and tries to compile them, rather than bundling them with your application as needed. Make sure that the shaders are being copied into your application bundle so that they can be accessed as a resource at runtime.